# Get all registered IOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there any way to retrieve all registered `IOptions` during runtime?

I have tried to retrieve them by injecting the `IServiceProvider` and then doing the following:

```
serviceProvider.GetServices(typeof(IOptions<>));
```

This doesn't work because you can't get services of open types:

> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot create arrays of open type.

Is there any other way, or do I have to keep track of the registered IOptions manually?